# Adding Custom Retina Image To TabBar In iOS5

Tags: xcode, image, ios5, tabbar

I am trying unsuccessfully to get my custom retina images to display in my custom iOS5 TabBar.

I have 4 items in my TabBar, I have set the selected/unselected image to contact@2x.png which has a resolution of 160px x 75px. I figured 4 of these 160px width images would accommodate the 640px retina width nicely.

You can view my contact@2x.png here 
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-afHulbEcxNE/TuPe-YIj91I/AAAAAAAAAII/lCojphAxF9w/s160/contact%2525402x.png

I have set all the items programtically as seen below.

```
UIImage *selectedContact = [UIImage imageNamed:@"contact@2x.png"];
UIImage *unselectedContact = [UIImage imageNamed:@"contact@2x.png"];

UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *item2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
UITabBarItem *item3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];

[item0 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedContact withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedContact];
[item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedContact withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedContact];
[item2 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedContact withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedContact];
[item3 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedContact withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedContact];
```

At runtime I can see that the scale is set to 1

Why isn’t the 2 being picked up off the image suffix? The tab bar is huge, and isnt scaled.

Please see the simulator screenshot below…

https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-A5oxZprlDhU/TuPfAlG_HQI/AAAAAAAAAIc/mIwHXOPZSrE/s735/simulator.png

My other retina images for my app icon and default icon are working.

Thoughts? I am driving myself nuts ☺ Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

JoePasq is wrong, he obviously is not up to date with the latest iOS5 appearance customisation API. Your problem could be that you specified the @2x in the filename, just pass "contact.png" to imagedNamed...

[UIImage imageNamed:@ "contact.png"]

Comment: Wow—he was talking about selection images and I was talking about the icons. I was off. I’ll update my answer. Thanks.

Comment: You are correct about the filename loading. From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW10): > “If the screen has a scale of 2.0, this method first searches for an image file with the same filename with an @2x suffix appended to it. For example, if the file’s name is button, it first searches for button@2x.”

Comment: The command should be:[UIImage imageNamed:@"contact"]; The .png is not required.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the documentation for customizing the appearance of [UITabBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007521-CH3-SW4)?

You should consult this tutorial by [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5) about using the UIAppearance APIs.

His code is this:

> ```
> UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bg"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
> [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];
> [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_select_indicator"]];`
> ```

Note that the customization happens on the Tab bar, not the tab bar items—assuming it’s the same customization for each one.

As [nbransby said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9422148/178805) you do not use @2x in the filename.

Prior unedited answer:

---

From the documentation:

> The images displayed on the tab bar are derived from this image. If this image is too large to fit on the tab bar, it is scaled to fit. The size of an tab bar image is typically 30 x 30 points. The alpha values in the source image are used to create the unselected and selected images—opaque values are ignored.

Your icons should be 30x30 px for normal resolution and 60x60 px for retina resolution. They should also be a solid color, the tab bar adds the coloring.

Comment: Tab bar icons, every version of iOS you can develop for.

Comment: My apologies, but I dont follow. I was under the impression from the HIG that I now have the option to specify an image instead over an icon. From the HIG I thought the API would scale if the @2x directive was present?

Comment: I'm using image and icon interchangeably. In either case it should be a solid monochrome color picture file, then the `UITabBar` adds the coloring. The docs measure size in points; the iPhone non-retina screen is 320 points across and 320 pixels across whereas a retina iPhone screen is 320 points across and 640 pixels across. Your contacts@2x.png image should be 60x60 px, your contacts.png image should be 30x30 px. (Smaller images will work, the tab bar will reposition it a bit.)

Comment: Points are an abstraction to display on a screen with varying amounts of pixels (we might eventually get a @4x retina-retina screen!)

Comment: If you look at some of the new iOS apps like apples find friends or even the new twitter, they are using full png images for each tab, and have drifted away from icons, seems like I have the right idea it's just that at runtime the scaling for retina is not occurring for me.

Comment: They're not using standard `UITabBar`s, they're using customized tab bars for those effects. *There is no runtime scaling of images*. You have to have two separate files; one at 30x30 resolution with a plain filename, and one with 60x60 resolution with a `@2x` suffix.

Comment: Again: each resource is an image/icon file of type `.png` with a normal version for non-retina screens and an @2x version for retina screens. These are [bitmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap) files—they are not scalable vector graphics. *iOS will scale them if told to but they will be ugly, pixelated, and turn away customers.* It will not scale them and look nice. You should be using full size resources for retina and non-retina screens.